# Google Data Studio: Write user input back into a Google Big Query table

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I want users to be able to respond to questions in a Google Data Studio report and feed the answers back into a Google Big Query table. It doesn't need to be Google Big Query it could be Google Cloud Storage instead. Is that possible at all with Google Data Studio?

Comment: It is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use Data Studio as an input mask and write the inputs to a Big Query table. I have written a Community Connector for that, but I can only give you the source code and you have to host it yourself.

https://script.google.com/d/16uE5pE2BiJFPt1h989hB_-heUCGPmI5cBDZaW4DKvn5aU9WYIFDPKnsI/edit?usp=sharing

https://github.com/sagr81/community-connectors/tree/master/DDL-BigQuery-write-data-into-tables

Comment: Hi Samuel, thanks for sharing your source code. I managed to connect it to my data studio but I didn't know how to set the chart to be "editable" so a user can fill in the columns. Can you give me some guidance please?

Comment: the dropdown filters and text filters act as input boxes. These value can be written to BigQuery. However, you cannot edit a table directly. By using cross filter a user can select a row of a table and input the desire value for one column defined beforhand.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Data Studio is for data visualization, not for input.

You can probably hack this behavior with Community Connector to some extent, but it will be a terrible user experience and you surely don't want to go through this path.